# Sharing settings for Google Calendar in an iCalendar file created by PHP

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I have a PHP script which makes an VCALENDAR file with events in it.
All is well and Google Calendar reads it from an URL or if I insert it manually.

The problem is, only I can see it.
I want the calendar to be viewable for everyone.
How can I achieve this by editing the VCALENDAR file?
So to set the agenda options (Anyone Can) to See all event details.
Now it is set (when someone else adds it) to Anyone can: View nothing.

Thanks in advance!

Bas

Answer (score 0):

Did you include a class component?

```
CLASS:PUBLIC
```

Wikipedia has more information about the [iCalendar format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar#Events_.28VEVENT.29).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I can properly test it when Google has synced my URL. I will let you know!